# Trouble centering fixed navigation bar

Tags: html, css, navigation, nav

Basically I'm looking to have a fixed navbar on my site, which moves with you when you scroll down. So far everything is good, but I'm really having trouble centering the bar.

HTML

```
<header id="header">
<nav id="nav">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#slide1">Front</a></li>
    <li><a href="#slide2">Mastering</a></li>
    <li><a href="#slide3">Samples</a></li>
    <li><a href="#slide4">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</header>
```

CSS

```
#header {
z-index: 1;
width: 100%;
height: 80px;
position: fixed;
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
display: block;
}

#nav { 
z-index: 1;
width:100%;
margin-top: 20px;
display: block;
position: fixed;
text-align:center;
}

#nav ul{
list-style: none;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 50%;
/* To help to identify the location */
height:50px;
background-color:green;
}

#nav li{
margin-top: 9px;
float: left;
padding-left: 21px;
display:block;
}
```

JSFiddle
    https://jsfiddle.net/kjr1591d/1/

Would love to have some help. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Like this https://jsfiddle.net/fabric/kjr1591d/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you looking for something like this-

```css
#header {
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    display: block;
}

#nav { 
    z-index: 1;
    width:100%;
    margin: 15px 0;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    text-align:center;
}

#nav ul{
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50%;
    /* To help to identify the location */
    height:50px;
    background-color:green;
    text-align:center;
    padding:0
}

#nav li{
    margin:15px 0 0;
    /*float: left;*/
    padding:0 10px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">           
    <nav id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#slide1">Front</a></li>
            <li><a href="#slide2">Mastering</a></li>
            <li><a href="#slide3">Samples</a></li>
            <li><a href="#slide4">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

[jiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kjr1591d/2/)

```
#nav ul{
list-style: none;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 80%;
/* To help to identify the location */
height:50px;
background-color:green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `ul` and `li`'s to display as `inline-block` and assign the `li`'s a left and right margin of equal sizing.